# Rest API throws 403 when using POST Fetch in React app

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, react

I have a React App which is deployed to SharePoint application folder in IIS. When I try to create a folder using rest api, it throws: http://sp2016:5155/_api/web/folders 403 (FORBIDDEN)

```
    const folderPostSettings = {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: 'same-origin', //used include as well
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "__metadata": {
          "type": "SP.Folder"
        },
        "ServerRelativeUrl": folderServerRelativeUrl
      }),
      headers: new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json; odata.metadata=full",
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
      })
    }
fetch(url,folderPostSettings).then(response);
```

I can't access the Formdigest here because it does not exist.
I have tried adding this line in the header: `"X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById('__REQUESTDIGEST').value`
 How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a request digest by sending a `POST` request to

```
http://server/site/_api/contextinfo
```

with only an `accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose'` header.

---

Apparently there is some confusion about what I am saying.

When SharePoint generates a page, it adds a hidden element with the ID `__REQUESTDIGEST`.  Usually, when you are writing code to call the REST API, and that code is *hosted on a page served by SharePoint*, you use

```
document.getElementById('__REQUESTDIGEST').value
```

in order to get the value of the request digest, so that you can then use it as the value of the `X-RequestDigest` header in your REST call.

If your code is *not* running on a page served by SharePoint, that hidden element will of course not be there, so trying to do

```
document.getElementById('__REQUESTDIGEST').value
```

will not work.

HOWEVER, there is *another way* to get that value.  Now, I've never used the `Headers` object, but following the pattern of OP's code sample, if you do this:

```
const url = 'http://sp2016:5155/_api/contextinfo';

const requestDigestPostSettings = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({
        'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
    })
}

fetch(url, requestDigestPostSettings).then(response => {

    const requestDigestValue = response.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;

    // now you can use the requestDigestValue in the X-RequestDigest header in your _next_ REST call
});
```

NOTE: I just tested this through Postman on a SP2013 site.  It seems that OP is using SP2016?  So I'm not sure if the *exact* structure of the response object will be `d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue`, but the digest value will be in the response somewhere.

The point being that you can get a request digest value by making a REST call to the site if you cannot get it through `document.getElementById`, which you can then turn around and use in the `X-RequestDigest` header of a *subsequent* REST call where you do what you are really trying to do in the first place.

Comment: how do I construct the url to create a folder using the `/_api/contextinfo`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  You use `/_api/contextinfo` to get the same request digest value that you would have got from `document.getElementById('__REQUESTDIGEST').value`.  You then have to turn around and make another REST call to create the folder, using the request digest value you got from `/_api/contextinfo` in the `X-RequestDigest` header of the new API call.

Comment: I did that but it does not find it. The value is null

Comment: Which value is null?  The response from sending a request to `/_api/contextinfo`, or the value of `document.getElementById('__REQUESTDIGEST').value`?

Comment: the value from `document.getElementById('__REQUESTDIGEST').value`

Comment: @BurreIfort updated my answer.

Comment: I will give it a try and get back to you.